# I have date and time two column in in database . the time is in h:i:A format. i want data which is before current date time

Tags: laravel

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d');
 $time = date('h:i:A');
 $limit = '20';
 $history=Booking::with('branch','user')->where('user_id',$this->user->id)->where('date','<',$date)->where('time','<',$time)->paginate($limit);
```

i want data which is before current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the whereDate and whereTime methods provided by the framework, from the docs:

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('h:i:A');
$limit = '20';
$history = User::with('branch', 'user')
  ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
  ->whereDate('date', '<', $date)
  ->whereTime('time', '<', $time)
  ->paginate($limit);
```

You can read more in the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: I think you should add orWhere to cover the case that we have the same created_at and the time before the current time

Comment: My time format in db is in varchar like 12:12 AM.